# What does "cannot first fail at" mean (set theory/GCH)?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on set theory (or the CH, I don't totally remember which right now) and it said something about it being provable in ZFC that the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis "cannot first fail at" $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ but I am having a heck of a time with the phrasing. I know it's meaningful and all but IDGI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that if $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for every $\kappa<\aleph_{\omega_1}$, then $2^{\aleph_{\omega_1}}=(\aleph_{\omega_1})^+$, in other words if $\mathsf{GCH}$ holds below $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, then it also holds at $\aleph_{\omega_1}$.

More generally, by a result of Silver, the first failure of $\mathsf{GCH}$ cannot be at a singular cardinal of uncountable cofinality.

Comment: Ok as soon as I can I will ✓ that answer, only other question is, does + mean the successor relation?

Comment: @Kristian Yes, $\kappa^+$ means the smallest cardinal above $\kappa$, so that $\mathsf{GCH}$ can be phrased as "for all $\kappa$, $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$".